# INET_ATON - mysql query to ms-sql query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
 $sql = 'SELECT 
            c.country 
        FROM 
            ip2nationCountries c,
            ip2nation i 
        WHERE 
            i.ip < INET_ATON("'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'") 
            AND 
            c.code = i.country 
        ORDER BY 
            i.ip DESC 
        LIMIT 0,1';
```

The query is in mysql. I am not able to find the equivalent of INET_ATON in ms-sql but unable to find. Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

If you still use PHP then you can use PHP function `ip2long`

and then replace

```
i.ip < INET_ATON("'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'")
```

by

```
i.ip < '.ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'
```

Comment: Not that straightforward, though. You need to follow the tip in the manual page regarding 32-bit platforms.